# React this.onChange() is not calling inside map function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, onchange

i am getting the following error when i use to call onChange function inside map method

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCheckChange' of undefined at onChange
```

my code is following

```
  getPlanCheckbox(jsonParseservicelist, bbuserid) {
        const returnresult = jsonParseservicelist.map(function (single) {
          return (
            <div className="">
              <label className="" >
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => this.onCheckChange(bbuserid, single.plantype)} defaultChecked={single.isActive == 1 ? "checked" : ""} />
                <span className="" />
              </label>
            </div>);
        });
        return returnresult;
      }



    onCheckChange = (e, bbuid, plantype) => {
        console.log(bbuid, plantype);

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i try this and i found 2 solution

1st is just replaced your function with following

```
getPlanCheckbox(jsonParseservicelist, bbuserid) {
    var self = this;
    const returnresult = jsonParseservicelist.map(function (single) {
      return (
        <div className="">
          <label className="" >
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => self.onCheckChange(bbuserid, single.plantype)} defaultChecked={single.isActive == 1 ? "checked" : ""} />
            <span className="" />
          </label>
        </div>);
    });
    return returnresult;
  }
```

just take `this` inside another `variable` and the user that variable name to call function 
lets say

```
var self = this;
```

now i use self to call the function like this

```
self.onCheckChange();
```

and 2nd is use map as arrow function

```
data.map((single) => {
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the map function as an arrow, because other wise, `this` won't be the global context. Same is applied for `getPlanCheckbox` function, if you haven't bound `this` in your constructor:

```
  getPlanCheckbox = (jsonParseservicelist, bbuserid) => {
        const returnresult = jsonParseservicelist.map((single) => {
          return (
            <div className="">
              <label className="" >
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => this.onCheckChange(bbuserid, single.plantype)} defaultChecked={single.isActive == 1 ? "checked" : ""} />
                <span className="" />
              </label>
            </div>);
        });
        return returnresult;
      }
```